# Web Audio API - Removing filter

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I'm building a visualiser with multiple graphic modes. For a few of them I need to calculate the beat of the track being played, and as I understand I then need to apply a lowpass filter like the following, to enhance frequencies that are most probable to hold drum sounds:

```
var filter = context.createBiquadFilter();

source.connect(filter);
filter.connect(context.destination);

filter.type = 'lowpass';
```

But what if I want to turn the filter off? Do I have to re-connect the source every time I need to remove the filter? Would this have any negative effect on performance?

Related question: how much performance loss would I experience if I have two two sources, from the same audio source, and apply the filter to one of them?

Comment: I don't understand. Why can't you just connect your single audio source to the destination directly, _and_ to a filter which you then connect to whatever you use to determine bpm?

Comment: @JohnWhite My problem is that I want to switch between a visualiser that reacts to all frequencies, and one that just reacts to beats. Are you suggesting I always have two sources, and one is always connected to the filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how much performance loss would I experience if I have two two sources, from the same audio source, and apply the filter to one of them

You can connect a single audio node to multiple destinations, thus you never need a duplicate source just to spread-connect it. If you need filtered and raw audio simultaneously, you can just setup your connections accordingly:

```
var filter = context.createBiquadFilter();

source.connect(filter);
source.connect(context.destination);
filter.connect(context.destination);

filter.type = "lowpass";
```

---

Anyways, setting the type property of a FilterNode to `"allpass"` will effectively disable all filtering, without having to reconnect:

```
filter.type = "allpass"
```

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking about all-pass, but according to MDN it "lets all frequencies through, but changes the phase-relationship between the various frequencies". I was afraid of the phase changes.

Answer (score 2):

According to article [WebAudio intro | html5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/), I would have to toggle the filter on and off, by disconnecting the source and itself like so:

```
  this.source.disconnect(0);
  this.filter.disconnect(0);
  // Check if we want to enable the filter.
  if (filterShouldBeEnabled) {
    // Connect through the filter.
    this.source.connect(this.filter);
    this.filter.connect(context.destination);
  } else {
    // Otherwise, connect directly.
    this.source.connect(context.destination);
  }
```

Comment: I'm leaving my question open in case someone comes with a better solution.

Comment: An alternative: Stick a gain node between the filter output and context.destination.  When you don't care about the filter output anymore, set the gain to 0.